# How to take the input while the user is typing in c++

Tags: c++, autocomplete

I want to make a program which does autocomplete when a user types in the console window. For that I will maintain a dictionary of words and output some of the words that starts with the same word user is typing. But how do I take the input while the user is still typing on console?

Comment: Look into a curses library.

Comment: You will need a platform specific function(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on Windows platform you can use PDCurses to get your characters one by one using getch(). you can find the documentation link
: [PDCurses.txt](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/PDCurses.txt) and [here's](https://jdonaldmccarthy.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/how-to-set-up-pdcurses-in-visual-studio-2013-c/) a tutorial how to set up PDCurses in visual studio.

If you are working on Linux, Unix or OS X you can use NCurses.

Hope this will help.